# Write a program that will print a table containing the integers from one to forty along with their squares, square roots, and reciprocals

Tags: java, math

```
public class Q6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Question 6");
        int square, number1, reciprocal;
        double squareRoot;
        System.out.println("Number\tSquare\tSquareRoot\tReciprocal");
        for (number1 = 1; number1 < 41; number1++)
        {
            square = (number1 * number1);
            squareRoot = Math.sqrt(number1);
            reciprocal = (1 / number1) + number1;
            System.out.println(number1+"\t"+square+"\t"+squareRoot+"\t"+reciprocal); 
            
        }

    }

}
```

**The question:** Write a program that will print a table containing the integers from one to forty along with their squares, square roots, and reciprocals.
**The problem:** Calculating the reciprocal doesn't work like it is supposed to. I have looked at other sites and they all say to divide the number by 1 and add the original number. However, my code won't work correctly. The program prints out the original number in the reciprocal column instead of the reciprocal, with an exception of the number 1, where it prints 2 in the reciprocal column.

Comment: I think you need the reciprocal to be a float

Comment: Ronan, "reciprocal" has always meant just 1 divided by the number. Are you sure you have the right definition of reciprocal? I think you need to declare `reciprocal` as a `double`, and then say `reciprocal = 1.0 / number1`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was thinking you had to actually print out the number like the reciprocal of 2 is 0.5 or something like that, this makes it a lot easier. Thanks for your help Robert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing by an Integer (**number1**).

Declare reciprocal variable as Double

```
double reciprocal;
```

And then cast the **number1** as double

```
reciprocal = (1 / (double)number1) + number1;
```